# Enabling a ContentProvider in a persistent process doesn't work properly?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-source

I don't know if anyone has tried this before but if you are developing an Android platform key signed `persistent` app with a ContentProvider that is enabled programmatically at runtime using `PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting(...)` you may discover that after enabling it other processes can see the provider (`ContentResolver#acquireContentProviderClient(...)` returns a non-null client), but all attempts to invoke the provider hang the caller forever. It doesn't matter if you use `PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP` or not. I'm not sure if this bug exists in all versions of Android but I am seeing it in Jelly Bean 4.2 (which isn't saying much since there seem to be lots of bugs in that version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to use `PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP` and then immediately invoke:

`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())`

Then the process will be restarted and the ContentProvider that was programmatically enabled will start working properly.